# Opening a file in Java inside a directory specified by wildcard characters

Tags: java, file, wildcard

In Java, is it possible to specifiy a directory using a wildcard character, when trying to create a file object as below?

```
File newFile = new File("\temp\*\path");
```

In this case, the directory is created by some other part of code which I don't have access to, which puts a timestamp in the name. So the problem would be solved if I can put * in place of the timestamp, like

```
 File newFile = new File("\temp\dirname-*\path");  // * is timestamp when directory was created.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a programmer, you should learn that statements like "I am sure that a single directory exists at that place" will be true until they are false (and they *will* be false at some point).

Do the work to look in `\temp\`, verify that there is only one directory, then open the file with the correct path.  Then when the precondition isn't true you can throw an exception or display a message.

Comment: well, the thing is that directory is created by someone else's code, which runs before I run mine. Also I can run my code only if the first chunk that creates the directory runs successfully. So I am sure the directory exists, and I am not trying to access any random directory.

Comment: @rgamber, then why do you need '*' if it is not a random directory :)?

Comment: @AndreyAdamovich,the directory name is based on a timestamp. I cannot precisely assume the creation time. Though if I am able to put a wildcard where the timestamp is, then the problem is solved. I should have mentioned this in the question!!

Comment: You say it's "based" off of the timestamp- is there any part of it that you can reliably know? E.g. If it's going to be `temp\dir1234567\path` then you could look for child folders of temp whose names start with "dir"

Comment: Yes..its something like temp\dir-1234567\path\file. Thats why I was trying to put a *: temp\dir-*\path\file.

Answer (score 1):

Creating it as you described is not possible. It is, however, possible to write an algorithm to search for a File that fits the description. In your case, you would want to create a `new File("temp")` then recursively search through its children (using the `listFiles` for any file whose `isDirectory` method returns true) for a file that is named `"path"`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use wild cards in file names in Java.

You will need to resolve the path yourself, but it is not hard.

You might find

```
new java.io.File("/tmp").listFiles();
```

an interesting place to start.